# Android Emulated SD Card

Tags: android

I have an android device which doesn't have an SD Card (It says "Insert SD Card" in Settings -> Storage.

But when i list the files in adb shell, it has a folder named /sdcard in it and it has files in it too.

I thought that it might be an emulates sdcard location coming from /storage/sdcard0. But the contents of the two folders are different. Can anyone help me understand this concept please? Couldn't find much by Googling.

Comment: Probably, your device has an **internal** storage.

Comment: Contact your device manufacturer and ask them.